Horror movie where wishes are granted in a museum & in prison
I only know the beginning of it and have no idea when it was made but saw it about 8 years ago:
It starts with a man and a woman robbing a museum they get hold of a stone that is knocked out of a ruin, the police invade the place and the man gets shot, this man (I'm presuming his the devil) asks if he has a wish the man on the floor wishes that he had never been born and then starts devolving.
Another scene is the man (again i think the devil) is arrested and put in a holding cell with other men he again asks if anyone has a wish in exchange for their soul, one man thinks he's an idiot and says "I wanna see me go through the bars of this cell" to which the Devil pushes him between two bars squishing all his insides out.
So any ideas I've tried searching everywhere?  

Sounds like Wishmaster 2. From Wiki:

During an attempted robbery of a museum, the fire opal that contains the Djinn is accidentally released by a stray gunshot. One of the burglars, a woman named Morgana Truscott, steals the gem and is forced to abandon her partner during the escape. The Djinn escapes and kills the remaining burglar when he accidentally wishes he'd never been born.

Here's that second scene in prison (WARNING: gory stuff) and the trailer.

It's Wishmaster 2, The Evil Never Dies. You nailed two of the scenes almost perfectly.
